# State not applied if I change state name inside done event of animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I need to update my state when animation done event trigger, but my code not working, but if I add some delay then work fine. I do not understand this behavior. please help me?

CSS File

```
.myblock {
    background-color: green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5rem;
}
```

HTML File

```
<div [@changeState]="currentState" (@changeState.done)="endState()" class="myblock mx-auto" ></div>
<button (click)="changeState()">Change state</button>
```

TS File

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-animation-example',
  templateUrl: './animation-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./animation-example.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('changeState', [
      state('state1', style({
      })),
      state('state2', style({
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        transform: 'scale(1.5)'
      })),
      transition('state2=>state1', animate('300ms')),
      transition('state1=>state2', animate('2000ms'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class AnimationExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  currentState = "state1";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  /* button click listener */
  changeState() {
      this.currentState = "state2";
  }
  endState() {
      this.currentState = "state1";
  }
}
```

[check link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lh6z4g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: what effect do you want to achive zoom out?

Comment: nothing, only css style applied.

Comment: why you going to state1 to state1 and you have not define any style inside state1

Comment: @Chellappan can you see above code link

Answer (score 0):

make it `this.currentState = "state2"` in endState() method like below, then your state will be changing and since you only have styles applied in state2, you should be able to see some changes.

```
export class AnimationExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  currentState = "state1";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  endState() {
    this.currentState = "state2";
  }
}
```